# How to Find Out Last Index of each() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, loops, indexing, each

I have something like this...

```
$( 'ul li' ).each( function( index ) {

  $( this ).append( ',' );

} );
```

I need to know what index will be for last element, so I can do like this...

```
if ( index !== lastIndex ) {

  $( this ).append( ',' );

} else {

  $( this ).append( ';' );

}
```

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Last element in .each() set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006822/last-element-in-each-set)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
var total = $('ul li').length;
$('ul li').each(function(index) {
    if (index === total - 1) {
        // this is the last one
    }
});
```

Comment: + For the good example, but this doesn't work while looping JSON object with named `keys` (`indexes`) since `index` is not a number.

Answer (score 14):

```
var arr = $('.someClass');
arr.each(function(index, item) {
var is_last_item = (index == (arr.length - 1));
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Remember to cache the selector `$("ul li")` because it's not cheap.

Caching the length itself is a micro optimisation though, that's optional.

```
var lis = $("ul li"),
    len = lis.length;

lis.each(function(i) {
    if (i === len - 1) {
        $(this).append(";");
    } else {
        $(this).append(",");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    var length = $( 'ul li' ).length
    $( 'ul li' ).each( function( index ) {
        if(index !== (length -1 ))
          $( this ).append( ',' );
        else
          $( this ).append( ';' );

    } );
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to do that:

```
$('ul li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':last-child')) {
        // Your code here
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

using jQuery .last();

```
$("a").each(function(i){
  if( $("a").last().index() == i)
    alert("finish");
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mvgun0gx/1/)

Comment: This usage more easy than others :) Thanks