# How to find the end of a .each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did look out for some other answers on SO in regards, and [from one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6061924/1018804) I found the one I am using on here, yet it looks like it's never happening as this isn't firing `return false;` neither the `console.log(myId);` which normally should.

```
      let pattern = new RegExp('^\/wiki\/');
      var total = doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').length;
      doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').each(function(i, el, index) { 
        var result = $(this).attr('href').replace(pattern, '');
        console.log(result);
        if (index === total - 1) {
          myId = item.pageid;
          console.log(myId);
          return false;
        }
      });
```

I even tried the following as suggested on [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8941358/1018804) with no positive results:

```
  let pattern = new RegExp('^\/wiki\/');
  doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').each(function(i, el) { 
    var result = $(this).attr('href').replace(pattern, '');
    console.log(result);
  }).promise().done( function(){ 
    myId = item.pageid;
    console.log(myId);
    return false;
  });
```

**UPDATE**

About: `item` 
(no issue with the following data), the above code is within the following `data each`:

```
  $.getJSON(url,function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
```

Comment: what is `item`?

Comment: @er-han updated with the answer to your question in case it is needed to others

Comment: Shouldn't you simply use `i` instead of `index` in your if statement?

Comment: @MehdiElFadil I could, but is it that you think that causes the problem?

Comment: Why do you need to be aware of when the last index is reached? What are you trying to achieve? `.promise()` will resolve a jQuery deferred object immediately if not chained to a function which returns a jQuery deferred object or a custom queue name

Comment: I think @Mehdi_El_Fadil is right

Comment: @MehdiElFadil it was indeed that, would you place it on as an answer and I will accept it? Other people have answered the same this and I'd want to accept the help

Comment: Also you'd better change `i` to something else because the upper `each` function has an `i` named argument too

Comment: @er-han yup, going to accept MTK answer as it kinda mentions that

Comment: If you just need the last anchor, using `last()` would be a much better option than iterating over all of them with `each()`

Comment: @er-han not really relevant as it is a closure

Comment: @charlietfl what if the upper iterating index is needed too? Maybe not now, but it is good for more readable code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first option have one sintax error:

> .each(function(i, el, index) must be .each(function(index, el)

```
 let pattern = new RegExp('^\/wiki\/');
  var total = doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').length;
  doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').each(function(index, el) { 
    var result = $(this).attr('href').replace(pattern, '');
    console.log(result);
    if (index === total - 1) {
      myId = item.pageid;
      console.log(myId);
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no third argument for `each()` callback. What you refer to as `index` is undefined. The first argument `i` is the index

Change to:

```
if (i === total - 1)
```

Comment: oh I see! testing now

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the variable `index` is not defined, so `if (index === total - 1)` never returns true.

The call to function `.each`:

```
.each(function(i, el, index)
```

should be

```
.each(function(i, el)
```

Then the test should be

```
if (i === total - 1)
```

cf [jQuery API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/), stating the two arguments taken by the function:

> .each( function )
>
> function Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.last()` function:

1.

```
//insert own jq function
$.fn.myTask = function(){
  myId = item.pageid;
  console.log(myId);
  //My suggestion: return this;
  return false;
}
```

2.

```
  //than replace your lines
  let pattern = new RegExp('^\/wiki\/');
  var total = doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').length;
  doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').each(function(i, el) { 
    var result = $(this).attr('href').replace(pattern, '');
    console.log(result);
  }).last().myTask();
```

Comment: thanks, will try this out now as it'd make it smaller